# Spring boot java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, web, web-development-server

I am trying to build `Spring-boot` CRUD application with Hibernate and REST -API.However when  I try to run the app everything is working fine but console is displaying the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.javabrains.EmployerController.getAllEmployers(EmployerController.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
```

I tried to change the value however it didnt work

EmployerService.java

```
package io.javabrains;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.javabrains.Entity.Employer;

@Service
public class EmployerService {

    private Repository repository;

    public List<Employer>getAllEmployers(){
        List<Employer>employers = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll()
        .forEach(employers::add);
        return employers;

    }

    public void addEmployer(Employer employer) {
        repository.save(employer);
    }    
}
```

EmployerController.java

```
package io.javabrains;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.javabrains.Entity.Employer;

@RestController
public class EmployerController {

    private EmployerService service;


     @RequestMapping("/employer") 
     public List<Employer>getAllEmployers()
     {
         return  service.getAllEmployers();
}
    /*
     * @RequestMapping("/employer/{id}") public Employer getEmployer(@PathVariable
     * int id) { return service.getEmployer(id); }
     */

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/employer/create")
    public void addEmployer(@RequestBody Employer employer) {
        service.addEmployer(employer);  
    }
}
```

....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the analysis of the code snippet given, the null pointer exception occurred since your code doesn't ask the spring dependency injector to inject  `EmployerService` as a dependency to `EmployerController`, so it doesn't inject the `EmployerService` bean class to the reference `private EmployerService employerService;` thus it is null in `EmployerController`. You can ask Spring Dependency Injector to inject dependency by adding `@Autowire` annotation `private EmployerService service;` refence in `EmployerController`

Update your `EmployerService` to the following will work

```
package io.javabrains;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.javabrains.Entity.Employer;

@RestController
public class EmployerController {

  //UPDATE : Autowiring
  @Autowired
  private EmployerService employerService;


  @RequestMapping("/employer")
  public List < Employer > getAllEmployers() {
    return service.getAllEmployers();
  }
  /*
   * @RequestMapping("/employer/{id}") public Employer getEmployer(@PathVariable
   * int id) { return employerService.getEmployer(id); }
   */

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/employer/create")
  public void addEmployer(@RequestBody Employer employer) {
    employerService.addEmployer(employer);
  }
}
```

And Also, the same issue would occur in `Service` when trying to access `repository`.

Update `EmployeeService.java` code include `@autorwired` logic:

```
package io.javabrains;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import io.javabrains.Entity.Employer;

@Service
public class EmployerService {

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    public List<Employer>getAllEmployers(){
        List<Employer>employers = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll()
        .forEach(employers::add);
        return employers;

    }

    public void addEmployer(Employer employer) {
        repository.save(employer);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private EmployerService employerService;
```

This mean you have created a reference variable of EmployerService not an object of EmployerService. Which can be done by using a `new` keyword. But as you know Spring Container uses DI(Dependency Injection) to manage a beans(an object, in above case object of EmployerService). So the object instantiation and whole lifecycle of an object is managed by the spring. For this we have to tell that the this object should be managed by the spring which is done by using `@Autowired` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get object of repository before using, for that add @Autowired on

```
private Repository repository;
```

in your EmployerService class.

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired is definitely the solution.

But your service class, if you ask for your REPOSITORY, you should put there too.

So in my problem, the solution was

```
@Autowired
private ProductService productService;
```

And

```
@Autowired
ProductRepository productRepository;
```

Answer (score 0):

there was a line inside a method that was throwing this **NullpointerException** then later on I put that line in the if statement and it worked for me seamlessly.
example:

`if (user != null) { application.setEmailaddress(user.getEmail());}`